# collections.MutableSequence subclass appears to be singleton?

Tags: python, abc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Least Astonishment” in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)

Playing around with code found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5104787/688305), I found the following weirdness.  Here's my class declaration, a totally trivial MutableSequence subclass:

```
import collections
class DescriptorList(MutableSequence):
    def __init__(self, items=[]):
        super(DescriptorList, self).__init__()
        self.l = items

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.l)

    def __getitem_(self, index):
        return self.l[index]

    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        self.l[index] = value

    def __delitem__(self, index):
        del self.l[index]

    def insert(self, index, value):
        self.l.insert(index, value)
```

Now, here's the weirdness:

```
Python 2.7.2 (v2.7.2:8527427914a2, Jun 11 2011, 15:22:34) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import DescriptorList
>>> b=DescriptorList()
>>> c=DescriptorList
>>> c=DescriptorList()
>>> c.append(5)
>>> b[:]
[5]
>>> b.append(6)
>>> c[:]
[5, 6]
>>> c
<DescriptorList object at 0x100ccfc50>
>>> b
<DescriptorList object at 0x100a32550>
```

Why are the instances appearing to share properties?

Comment: don't put `items=[]` as default argument, put `items=None` and test for None in the body of __init__ to assign an empty list. Then understand why it's working this way by looking at @delnan comment

Comment: Great spot on that dupe.  I come from Ruby and this strikes me as just crazy.  If someone wants to post that as an answer, I'll approve it and move on.  Thanks!