# constraint list to take only integers

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to extend list type to take only integers. I did override **append**, **setitem** but it is not working. Any pointers please?

```
class linked_list(list):

    def __init__(self):
        self.indx = 0

   def next(self):
        self.indx += 1
        return self.__getitem__(self.indx)

    def prev(self,indx):
        self.indx -= 1
        return self.__getitem__(self.indx)


    def __append__(self,val):
        if not isinstance(val,int):
            raise Exception('only integers accepted')
        super(linked_list,self).__append__(val)


    def __getitem__(self,indx):
        try:
            return super(linked_list,self).__getitem__(indx)
        except IndexError,e:
            StopIteration()

    def __setitem__(self,key,val):
        if not isinstance(val,int):
            raise Exception('only integers accepted')

        super(linked_list,self).__setitem__(key,val)
```

Comment: Subclassing built-in types is generally a **bad** idea. You have to redefine *tons* of methods and even implement some methods not defined by `list`, otherwise you could find things like `['some', 'string'] + YourList([1,2,3])` which will defeat all your checks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By inheriting from [`collections.MutableSequence`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) instead of `list` you may get away with less code. `MutableSequence` will automatically implement all the other list methods based on the five methods below.

```
from collections import MutableSequence

class IntList(MutableSequence):
    def __init__(self):
        super(IntList, self).__init__()
        self._list = []

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._list)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self._list[index]

    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        if not isinstance(value, int):
            raise TypeError('only integers accepted')
        self._list[index] = value

    def __delitem__(self, index):
        del self._list[index]

    def insert(self, index, value):
        if not isinstance(value, int):
            raise TypeError('only integers accepted')
        self._list.insert(index, value)
```

On the flip side, this is not as efficient as overriding all the `list` methods manually -- for example, the `extend` method provided by `MutableSequence` will call `__len__` and `__insert__` once for each element. This can be amended by overriding any performance-sensitive methods and doing it more efficiently.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5104787/566644) answer for examples of how `MutableSequence` uses the methods above to implement the remaining `list` methods.

Answer (score 5):

It's not `__append__`, it's simply `append`. Also `TypeError` is probably a more suitable exception.

```
def append(self,val):
    if not isinstance(val, int):
        raise TypeError('only integers accepted')
    super(linked_list,self).append(val)
```

As @TimPietzcker noted, you should also override `extend` and other methods appropriately

Comment: Wouldn't you also have to override `extend()`?

Comment: Not only `extend` but also things like `__add__` and even define `__radd__`(which is not defined by `list`) otherwise `['a'] + TheList([1,2,3])` will call `list.__add__`.

Comment: Thanks, just figured that.

Answer (score 2):

You should be defining an `append` method, not `__append__`. You should also override `__add__`, `__iadd__`, `insert` and `extend`.